# Unable to call super() inside constructor() in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I'm trying to write a react app with typescript support using create-react-app  --scripts-version=react-scripts-ts command.

I keep seeing this error:

> (23,15): error TS2345: Argument of type 'Props | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Props'.
>         Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Props'.

The code that this is coming from is this:

```
export class ScratchpadComponent extends React.Component<ScratchpadComponent.Props, ScratchpadComponent.State> {

    constructor(props?: ScratchpadComponent.Props, context?: any) {
        super(props, context);
        this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
    }
```

Not sure what is causing this - I've searched around and don't have much clue on how to resolve this?

Update:

If I remove the optional ? from the constructor signature, then I start seeing this error:

```
18,11): error TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<Pick<Props, "dispatch" | "scratchPadActi...'.
  Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<Pick<Props, "dispatch" | "scratchPadActions" | "scratchData" | "errorMessage" | "errorDa...'.
    Property 'dispatch' is missing in type '{}'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The superclass constructor expects Props as its first argument. The subclass constructor can be called without any argument, since you declared it as

```
constructor(props?: ScratchpadComponent.Props, context?: any)
```

and not as

```
constructor(props: ScratchpadComponent.Props, context?: any)
```

So, if the caller doesn't pass any argument, then props is undefined, and you're trying to pass undefined to the super constructor, which doesn't accept undefined.

Comment: Hey I just removed the optional signature from the component definition and have updated my question with the error that I'm now seeing. Do you know how to get rid of this error?